# Weibel Exercise 3.3.1 how to prove $\operatorname{Ext}_Z^1(Z[1/p],Z)\cong\hat{Z}_p/Z$ without writing down the map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

$\def\Z{\Bbb Z}$This is related to Weibel Exercise 3.3.1 Show that $\operatorname{Ext}_\Z^1(\Z[1/p],\Z)\cong\hat{\Z}_p/\Z\cong \Z_{p^\infty}$.

I have done the problem by the following way. Take the short exact sequence of the followings.

$0\to \Z\to \Z[1/p]\to \Z_{p^\infty}\to 0$ $(\star_0)$

Use projective resolution as the following.

$0\to \Z\to \Z\to 0$

$0\to\oplus_i(p^i\Z)\to \Z\oplus[\oplus_i(\Z)]\to \Z[1/p]\to 0$ $(\star_2)$

$0\to \oplus_i(p^i\Z)\to \oplus_i \Z\to \Z_{p^\infty}\to 0$ $(\star_3)$

$(\star_2)$'s construction is done by horseshoe lemma. One note that $(\star_2)$'s inclusion are given by canonical inclusion $\oplus_i(p^i\Z)\to\oplus_i \Z$ whereas $(\star_3)$ is inclusion is given by $z\to (0,z)$. Now I can compute directly using resolution by seeing $0\to \operatorname{Hom}(\Z,\Z)\xrightarrow{\delta} \operatorname{Ext}^1(\Z[1/p],\Z)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\Z_{p^\infty},\Z)\to 0$ where $\delta$ is concretely given by inclusion pullback and this identifies $Z\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(\Z_{p^\infty},\Z)$ by $1\in \Z\to 1\in \hat{\Z}_p$. Thus I can conclude $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\Z(\Z[1/p],\Z)\cong\hat{\Z}_p/\Z\cong \Z_{p^\infty}$ where $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\Z_{p^\infty},\Z)=\hat{\Z}_p$ by pulling direct limit out.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is it possible to identify $\operatorname{Ext}^1_\Z(\Z[1/p],\Z)\cong \Z_{p^\infty}$ without identifying the coboundary operator action? (i.e. There are too many possible ways that $\Z$ sits inside $\hat{\Z}_p$. I need to identify a particular one and quotient that out.)

Comment: You could try to find an injective resolution for $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Max it is easy to see there is ses $0\to Z\to Q\to Q/Z\to 0$ which gives rise to $0\to Hom(Z[1/p],Q)\xrightarrow{i_\star}\to Hom(Z[1/p],Q/Z)\to Ext^1(Z[1/p],Z)\to 0$. Furthermore $Q/Z=\prod_p Z_{p^\infty}$. So $Hom(Z[1/p],Q/Z)=Hom(Z[1/p],Z_{p^\infty})=Q_p$  and $Hom(Z[1/p],Q/Z)=Z_p$. So $Q_p/Z_p=(Q/Z)[p^\infty]$ which is $Z_{p^\infty}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ is the direct sum of these guys, not their product. However, the $\mathbb Z/q^\infty, q\neq p$ factors of any map from $\mathbb Z[1/p]$ are easily controlled because those groups are $p$-divisible, the only problem comes from  computing $\hom(\mathbb Z[1/p], \mathbb Z/p^\infty)$, which you did. Then $\hom(\mathbb Z[1/p], \mathbb Q)$ is easy to compute and so is the map relating the two

Comment: @Max Thanks a lot for clarification.

Comment: There is a mistake in the statement of this exercise. It is true that $Ext^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p],\mathbb{Z}) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}$,  but it is not true that $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$. For instance, because $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion-free and $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ is not.

Comment: @Goa'uld: That is correct and noted in the errata [here](http://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/602/bookerrors.pdf). Instead of $\Bbb Z_{p^{\infty}}$, it should be $(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z[1/p]) \times \hat{\Bbb Q}_p/\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you guys might be over-complicating things, and what Weibel had in mind is the following.
Consider the short exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
  0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[1/p] \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}} \to 0.
\end{equation*}
As $(\mathrm{Ext}^n(\bullet, \mathbb{Z}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a universal cohomological $\delta$-functor, we have the following long exact sequence
\begin{align*}
  0 \to &\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}, \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \to \\
  &\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}, \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z}) \to \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \to \dots.
\end{align*}

However, $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ because if $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z})$, $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then for $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(a/p^n) = p^mf(a/p^{m + n})$, which implies that $p^m$ divides $f(a/p^n)$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$, which means $f(a/p^n) = 0$ and consequently, $f = 0$.

We know from the book that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}, \mathbb{Z}) = \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p$.

Thus, we have obtained the following short exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
  0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p \to \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z}) \to 0,
\end{equation*}
and this means $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}[1/p], \mathbb{Z}) \cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}$ (here, we need to know how $\mathbb{Z}$ is embedded into $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p^{\infty}}$, but I am sure it is in the natural way).