# What conditions do we need to calculate: $\mathrm{Ext}(\Bbb Q,M)\cong\left(\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{M}_p\right)/M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

$\newcommand{\ext}{\mathsf{Ext}}\newcommand{\hom}{\mathsf{Hom}}$Let $\ext$ denote the first Ext functor over Abelian groups.

On page $85$ of Weibel's "An introduction to homological algebra", we are told that (in far more general terms):

> For any Abelian group $A$ filtered by $A_0\subseteq A_1\subseteq\cdots$ and any other Abelian group $B$, there is a short exact sequence: $$0\to\varprojlim_{i\in I}\sideset{^1}{}{\hom(A_i,B)}\to\ext(A,B)\to\varprojlim_{i\in I}\ext(A_i,B)\to0$$

Where $I$ is the posetal category on $\Bbb N_0$ with reverse order, $\cdots\to2\to1\to0$, and where appears the first derived inverse limit functor. We use this to calculate $\ext(\Bbb Z_{p^\infty},B)\cong\hat{B}_p$ (the $p$-adic completion $\varprojlim_{i\in I}B/p^iB))$ in the instance that $B$ is torsionfree.

It is left as an exercise to use this formula to compute $\ext(\Bbb Z[1/p],\Bbb Z]\cong\hat{\Bbb Z}_p/\Bbb Z$ using the filtration $\Bbb Z[1/p]=\bigcup_{i\in I}p^{-i}\Bbb Z$. To be honest, I'm not sure how that works. The analogous $\ext(A_i,B)$ terms vanish, and then it remains to compute the *derived* inverse limit of $\cdots\to B\overset{p}{\to}B\overset{p}{\to}B\to\cdots\overset{p}{\to}B$. This seems hard. It's easy to get the claim using other properties of Ext though.

More generally, I claim that if $B$ has no $p$-torsion and also no nonzero elements divisible by arbitrarily high powers of $p$, then $\ext(\Bbb Z[1/p],B)\cong\hat{B}_p/B$. For the short exact sequence $0\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[1/p]\to\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\to0$ yields an exact sequence: $$0\to\hom(\Bbb Z,B)\cong B\to\hat{B}_p\to\ext(\Bbb Z[1/p],B)\to0$$Giving the claim. Here I have used $\hom(\Bbb Z[1/p],B)=0$ and $\ext(\Bbb Z,B)=0$. The first claim is true because any nonzero homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z[1/p]\to B$ would have that $f(1)=pf(1/p)=p^2f(1/p^2)=\cdots$ is somehow infinitely divisible by $p$, forcing $f(1)=0$ - but then $f(1/p)$ is zero , since $B$ has no $p$-torsion etc. and it follows by induction that $f$ is zero.

Moving on, we are asked to compute $\ext(\Bbb Q,B)\cong\left(\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{B}_p\right)/B$ when $B$ is torsionfree. There is an exact $0\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\cong\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}\to0$, and we infer an exact: $$\hom(\Bbb Q,B)\to B\to\ext(\bigoplus_{p\text{ prime}}\Bbb Z_{p^\infty},B)\to\ext(\Bbb Q,B)\to0$$

**If** we assume $B$ does not contain an infinitely divisible element, as well as being torsionfree, then the $\hom(\Bbb Q,B)$ term vanishes and we can conclude. However, if $B=\Bbb Q$ say, then actually $\hom(\Bbb Q,B)\to\hom(\Bbb Z,B)$ is an isomorphism and it follows $\ext(\Bbb Q,\Bbb Q)\cong\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{\Bbb Q}_p$ *with no quotient*. (well, that doesn't matter here since $\Bbb Q/p^i\Bbb Q=0$ for all $p$ and $i$ and this product is actually zero. But it should matter in general)

> Am I right in thinking Weibel made an error in the question, that his formula is invalid without further hypotheses (e.g. $B$ has no infinitely divisible element)?

As a bonus (though I realise too many questions in one post is bad) I would appreciate insight on how to compute $\ext(\Bbb Z[1/p],-)$ using the derived limit formula.

Comment: One brief comment: $\mathsf{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q})=0$ because $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective: $\mathsf{Ext}(A, \mathbb{Q})=0$ for any $A$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri thanks that was certainly an easier way lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say Weibel made an error so much as that his notation is a little imprecise.  When he writes $\left(\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{B}_p\right)/B$, he really means the quotient of $\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{B}_p$ by the *image* of the canonical homomorphism from $B$.  This statement remains true by the exact sequence you wrote down, even if that canonical homomorphism is not injective (and indeed, its kernel is exactly the elements of $B$ that can come from homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}\to B$).

As for the $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[1/p],\mathbb{Z})$ computation, the $\lim^1$ formula tells you it is isomorphic to $\lim^1$ of the inverse system $A=\dots\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ where the maps are all multiplication by $p$, which can be identified with $\dots\to p^2\mathbb{Z}\to p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ where the maps are just the inclusions.  One easy way to compute this $\lim^1$ is to consider the short exact sequence of inverse systems $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, where $B$ is the constant system $\mathbb{Z}$ and $C$ is the inverse system $\dots\to\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to 0$.  Then the exact sequence $$0\to\lim A\to \lim B\to\lim C\to {\lim}^1 A\to {\lim}^1 B$$ gives $\lim^1 A\cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p/\mathbb{Z}$ since $\lim B=\mathbb{Z}$, $\lim C=\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p$, and $\lim^1 B=0$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The trick of replacement by the tower of $p^n\Bbb Z$ was useful. I considered your $B$ and $C$ but couldn't get a chain map.

Comment: If one replaces $\Bbb Z$ with a $B$ that contains no element infinitely divisible by $p$ and no $p$-torsion, am I right in thinking the exact same $\lim^1$ argument works?

Comment: Hm. Another thing is that the map into Ext is generally mysterious to make explicit. How can I know what the image of $B$ actually looks like?

Comment: The same calculation works for any $B$ with no $p$-torsion.  It doesn't matter if $B$ has elements infinitely divisible by $p$.

Comment: The way I would think about the image of $B$ is that $\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\hat{B}_p$ is the inverse limit of $\dots\to B/3!B\to B/2!B\to B$, and you're just taking the canonical map from $B$ to this inverse limit.  In other words, by completing with respect to all primes at once, you don't have to try to make sense of the diagonal into a big product (though the completion itself might be harder to understand).

Comment: I think if $B$ has elements infinitely divisible by $p$ then $\lim A$ is nonzero and this should add an extra kernel, so we don’t quite get $\hat{B}_p/B$ but some larger group $\hat{B}_p/X$ where $X$ is $B$ quotient the subgroup of elements infinitely divisible by $p$.

Comment: As for the image of $B$, that’s a nice insight to have. I’m concerned however how we can be sure that that’s an accurate description; the construction of the connecting homomorphism of Ext is understandable but quite painful to follow through in detail. It’s unclear to me how you can know for sure that the induced map from $B$ is the limiting map you say.

Comment: The short exact sequence $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\to 0$ can be written as the direct limit of short exact sequences $0\to \mathbb{Z}\to\frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z}\to 0$, so the connecting homomorphism $B\to\prod\hat{B}_p$ will just be the inverse limit of the connecting homomorphisms $B\to \operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/n!\mathbb{Z},B)$ of these short exact sequences.  This connecting homomorphism can be computed easily enough with explicit free resolutions, which are very simple in this case.

Comment: (Alternatively, here is a sort of a hack to "compute" the connecting homomorphism without actually ever going back to the definition.  By naturality of everything in $B$, it suffices to compute it in the case $B=\mathbb{Z}$.  Also observe that $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})$ must be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space (by considering the endomorphisms $1/n:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$ which are inverse to multiplication by $n$)...

Comment: ...So we must be quotienting the profinite integers $\prod \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ by some cyclic subgroup and getting a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  The generator we are quotienting by cannot be divisible by any prime (since then we would have torsion in the quotient), and also cannot be $0$.  It follows that the generator must be a $p$-adic unit on each coordinate.  So, up to an automorphism of $\prod \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p$ (multiplying by the inverses of those $p$-adic units), it must just be $1$ on each coordinate.)

Comment: I'll think about this. Thank you very much for your time and insights

Comment: I see what you mean now about $p$-divisibility issues being irrelevant. I was weirdly obsessed with my maps being injective, when all that mattered was the image. Thanks once again